# Do you know how to change not the color but the style of indent guide line on a file explorer of vscode? (e.g. dotted or dashed line)

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: 1]

Do you know how to change not the color but the style of indent guide line on a file explorer of vscode? (e.g. dotted or dashed line)

[settings.json]

```
"workbench.tree.indent": 20,
"workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides": "always",
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#81E0FE",
```

Thank you all

Comment: find the name of the theme color and customize it